# Can you use "crime scene" for a suicide?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Example:

> The detectives assigned to Kevin's suicide left the house. I took the opportunity to investigate the
>   crime scene.

I'm not sure if this is correct. Since suicide isn't a *crime*. Or maybe crime scene in this case means "a place where a death happened"?

If I can't use the phrase, which other is available?

Comment: You could just use scene.

Comment: Suicide **is** a crime [in quite a few places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_legislation), but even there, I suspect _scene_ would be used more than _crime scene_.

Comment: It's silly to handcuff dead people who killed themselves...

Comment: @JasperLoy Maybe it only applies to those who failed to kill themselves.

Comment: @JasperLoy ‘Silly’ and ‘law’ are fairly orthogonal concepts—lots of things that are The Law are quite silly.

Comment: This question is not about the English language. It's essentially about the definition of *suicide*, of *crime*, and of *crime scene*; as it is about whether suicide is considered a crime. May be asked on relevant SE site.

Comment: @kris This question is about the English language, because "crime scene" and "suicide" are everyday phrases.

Comment: I've been thinking ... how about "suicide scene"? Is that common?

Comment: It may be common parlance to call any situation where police arrive after the event a 'crime scene' even if nominally no crime has taken place. 'scene' is probably sufficient.

Comment: @Jasper Loy Suicide is a crime so that people who attempt to commit suicide can be given treatment forcibly, because they attempted to commit a crime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard it just referred to as *the scene*.

(Isn't it a crime in some places?)

Comment: It might be a crime in some places, but how would you punish the perpetrator?

Comment: Please use "comments" to post opinions. You may have to wait till you earn the privilege to post comments.

Comment: @DanBron Attempted suicide would be punishable if it were a crime. It used to be criminalized in a lot of places, including most of the United States, but not anymore. I think it should be.

Comment: @nomad You think it should be? What punishment would you recommend for those who are so unhappy that they wish to end their own lives? Perhaps these people are so iniquitous they deserve the death sentence?

Comment: @DanBron Like any crime that negatively impacts other people, it should be punishable by prison time or some form of mandatory rehabilitation. I don't have all the details worked out because I'm not a lawmaker, but suicide is about as reprehensible as any other crime that takes someone's life. If the idea is that punishment scares people away from committing crimes, I think criminalizing suicide would save a lot of lives.

Comment: @nomad, Except suicide, by definition, is the stated desire of the "victim" (i.e. it's "consensual"). Murder (or even manslaughter), by definition, is not. In the case that someone murders a person who has no family or friends or anyone to mourn him, at least one person has been deprived of something he deeply values (his own life). In the case of a suicide with no family, friends, etc, that's not true.  Your analogy doesn't hold water.  And wouldn't counselling (i.e. a positive sanction) be, logically and ethically, a more appropriate response than punishment?

Comment: (Obligatory position statement: a person, if he owns anything, owns his own life.)

Comment: @DanBron Even someone who has no family or friends (very uncommon), he/she is causing a lot of costs to the government, to the owner of the premises on which he/she committed the act, etc. The severity of the punishment for attempted suicide could vary based on the impact it would've caused. Just an idea to try to prevent people from doing it and to think about why it's wrong and reprehensible.

Comment: @kris In a way, this "comment" does answer the question, at least partially.

Comment: @JasperLoy What is an answer and what is a comment?

Comment: @JasperLoy The *comment* in your comment does not need scare quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

[British Transport Police: Fatality Guidance Manual, 2012](http://www.btp.police.uk/pdf/FOI%20Response%20994-13%20BTP%20Fatality%20Guidance%20Manual.pdf)

You will note from the above guidance that the British Transport Police refer to the '*scene*' whilst assessing and investigating deaths on transport networks. A crime scene examiner is deployed to all suspicious/unexplained fatalities. Page 14 contains a flowchart showing that a '*crime scene*' is established ONLY on observing signs of related suspicious activity. Suicide is not a crime in the UK.

Suggested phrases include: '*scene of death*' and '*scene of suicide*', once this has been established as the cause of death.